# How does this art work balance itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

The artist Ariel Uzal* is showing a piece at UCLA that consists of a platform that is being moved on a horizontal plane by a rotating motor with an attached arm. The motor is moving at a constant speed.

On this platform, a tall un-attached wooden structure is balancing back and forth, seemingly "right-ing" itself and not toppling over.

[Here's a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z885v5ddz1fb3pw/Video%20May%2030%202023%2C%2011%2000%2035%20PM.mov?dl=0). [Here's another high resolution video](https://vimeo.com/841683150).

Below are also some image stills.

What physical phenomenon/process would best describe what's going on? Is this a form of double/triple pendulum, or a kind of tuned mass damper...?

My physics knowledge is limited so a "simple" explanation would be appreciated. :-)

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

* Disclaimer - Ariel is also a friend.

Comment: Definitely a tuned mass damper, with the lamp as the tuned mass. It is not an easy thing to study.

Comment: Thank you @naturallyInconsistent! Ariel also notes that without the lamp, the wooden structure rights itself just as much. Does it mean that the whole structure is a mass damper..? Thanks

Comment: Maybe what is happening is that the amplitude of the horizontal shaking is just not big enough to cause the wooden structure alone to topple. Again, this is a complicated thing to study and you might need to pop over to engineering SE to get a detailed answer.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the structure seems to modulate the motion of the platform.

Comment: Maybe it is a bit too obvious to even mention this, but the core principle at work here is just Inertia. The structure is constantly trying to maintain its present state of motion. Upon seeing this I immediately recalled [this](https://youtu.be/Zjm8JeDKvdc) anecdote by Feynman ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum
where the mass center is above the rotation axis.

Thus this pendulum is instable and has to be brought back to equilibrium through an appropriate periodic force ( here the rotating engine making the horizontal plate oscillate ).